# Where to find details of dimensions and doping of a typical bjt

Tags: bjt, datasheet, common-emitter, base, dimensions

I have been searching for dimensions and doping levels of base, emitter and collector for a typical bipolar junction transistor presently in use. I have tried searching on internet and seen datasheets for bc547 however they contain only voltage limits and transister characteristic graphs.Kindly provide the required data source.

Comment: You will not find this as these "recipes" are "company confidential" information, even for such an ancient device as the BC547. Also, this information is only relevant to people with access to or who are working with a Fab which can produce these transistors. You could read articles on transistor fabrication to get an idea of typical doping levels but information for a commercial device will be hard to get.

Comment: Andy Grove wrote a book on semiconductors, about 1960.

Comment: Can't we obtain I-V characteristics for Base-Emitter and then Base-collector diode by isolating the third pin in each case and then obtain diffusion capacitance parameters experimentally or any other such property and then obtain doping profile qualitatively and quantitatively ?

Comment: I found it exceedingly difficult to get doping information from Hamamatsu for its photodiodes I was interested in. However.... It's not hard to infer the information if you perform experiments, record the data, and then work backward using 3D integrals as a starting point. (The dimensions are measurable.) They really cannot hide the details well against good tests and application of theory. So if you want it bad enough, you can work it out. And yes, that includes BJTs.